# How can I pass text with & symbol from ajax to php code?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

I am new to php and I am doing a billing software, my problem "When they billing a mail will send to a specific email address", email is working perfectly. When I pass the symbol **&** , the mail was sent but after the **&** symbol text were gone. I need to use some words like "customer Name & Address" in first word I receive the text only **customer Name** remaining & Address was missing. How can I solve this problem?

```
var strVar="";
strVar += "<html>\n";
strVar += "<body>\n";
strVar += "\n";
------
------
strVar += "<div>\n";
strVar += "<center>Customer Name & Address<br><\/center>\n";
strVar += "<\/div>\n";
strVar += "<\/body>\n";
strVar += "<\/html>\n";
strVar += "\n";

        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "sendmail.php",
            data: "htmldata="+strVar ,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(resp) {
                debugger;

                alert("Message Sent Successfully");

            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.dir("Contact Administrator");
            }
        });
```

In server side I am using normail PHPMailer concept.

Comment: Aside from your problem, but ***never, ever use async: false***. It is incredibly bad practice as it hangs the UI until the request completes, making the browser look like it crashed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You are right, but I need to update the values in database after sending the mail.

Comment: That's still no reason to use `async: false`. Call a function in the `success` handler which makes the database update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this small but important change:

```
data: {
    htmldata: strVar
}
```

That will take care that your data is encoded correctly inside your post.

Apart from that: why would you want to create html on the client side and send it to the server?!?

Comment: Because, I like client side code. I am not familier in php. Thanks for your answer. It is working.

Comment: @MerbinJoe but you are aware that this means that the client can provide whatever html code some bad girl feels like having a try with? This sounds like a _huge_ security gap. You simply can never rely on what a client hands over.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will change it to server side code.

Comment: @MerbinJoe Glad I could help. Also keep in mind to validate the content of whatever data you receive before inserting it into server side generated html markup. Or at least use `htmlescape()` on it...